# Cross platform video chat using Quickblox

Tags: cross-platform, quickblox, videochat

I am working on a application where I need to integrate video chat feature on different platforms. I am currently using Quickblox.

For iOS Platform I am using: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios

Android Platform : https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android

Web Platform : The JS API

Independently I can video chat between 2 users on Web or between 2 users on iPhone but after multiple attempts I have not been able to start a video chat session between 1 user on Web and 1 user on iOS.

Please, let me know is it possible to have video chat, i.e. video conferencing for all 3 platforms (iOS, Android & Web)?

Are there better ideas for implementation of this video chat requirement?

Comment: checkout my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117314/2437655 on quickblox integration which support all the three platforms

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very old question any way. They didn't complete webRTC implementation yet, once they have done you can continue with Quickblox otherwise you have to search any other apis. Please refer the below link.

http://quickblox.com/blog/webrtc-powered-cross-platform-video-calling-code-samples-web-ios-and-android/